Why does docker-compose volume have 2-way access
I'm asking for someone to explain how Docker and Compose handle volumes differently.
I'm setting up a dev env where I can run a container, serve a node app with --watch flag, edit the code locally and see changes instantly from the host.
I have a Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.4

FROM node:23-alpine as builder
EXPOSE 3000

RUN mkdir /project
WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install -g express

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .
CMD node --watch src/index.js

and a compose.yaml
services:
  express:
    build:
      context: .
      target: builder
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - NODE_PATH=/project/node_modules
    volumes:
      - .:/project
      - /project/node_modules

If I run just the docker container, it won't reflect local changes. If I run docker compose up it will reflect local changes.
If I add the same VOLUME definitions to Dockerfile, the changes don't reflect.
I haven't found why this is from the docs.
I thought you would need to define mounts to achieve something like this, but with compose it magically just works out-of-the-box. Why?

Dockerfile VOLUME tells the system that the directory contains data, not code, and that Docker needs to persist it across container executions (ignoring changes even in the image).  Docker creates an anonymous volume for the directory if you don't use a Compose volumes: option, and you cannot specify the location in the Dockerfile.
